# Custom Navigation Bar Subview does not hide when a new viewcontroller is pushed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

So on my `HomeViewController` I added a custom Navigation Bar `@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UIView!` and I'm adding it to the navigation bar as:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
self.navigationController?.view.insertSubview(navBar, belowSubview: navigationController!.view)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Now when I push `MenuViewController`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuVC") as! MenuViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This custom `navBar` is still on the top. I want the default navigation bar to show again as I only want custom `navBar` on `HomeViewController`

Comment: Best would have been to not use a navigation bar but a custom view on your current VC. and navigationBar on all other. Just an opinion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have added that custom `navbar` into the `navigationController.view`,
  that's why it will be seen on every `viewController` where `navigationController` is or will be used.

**You can do following to solve this**

- Add that `navbar` into subview of current `UIView`

`self.view.addSubview(navbar)`

- Hide the `navigationBar` from that particular `UIViewController`

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

- show it to the next `ViewController`

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)`

Answer (score 1):

Either you should remove the customView from your `navigationController` before pushing your `MenuViewController` or access the customview using its tag from `MenuViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` and remove it from superview or hide it